# Вывод данных из массива

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день.
Вот, допустим, есть некий массив.
array
(
[0] => 0
[1] => green
[2] => red
[3] => text
[4] => 1
[5] => blue
[6] => grey
[7] => txt
)
Как вывести данные в следующей последовательности:

Num: 0
Color: green
Color2: red
ID: text

Num: 1
Color: blue
Color2: grey
ID: txt

То есть данные в массиве извлекаются через определенное число, например тут через 4.
Вывести 2 раза еще можно, а если этот массив будет состоять из 1000 элементов?

Comment: >а если этот массив будет состоять из 1000 элементов

А может быть данные запаковать более удобным способом, например так:

    array(
       [0]=>array('num'=>0, 'color'=>'green', 'color2'=>'grey', 'ID'=>'text'),
       [1]=>array('num'=>0, 'color'=>'red', 'color2'=>'grey', 'ID'=>'txt')
    );

Comment: Я пример привел массива, там он состоит из 15 элементов, и так далее И этот массив берется из строк файла. Но спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$length = sizeof($data);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $length) {
    echo sprintf('Num: %d Color: %s Color2: %s ID: %s'.PHP_EOL, $data[$i], $data[$i+1], $data[$i+2], $data[$i+3];
    $i += 4;
}
```

массив, естественно, должен иметь длину, кратную четырем, иначе все вывалится в ошибку.

Comment: А если основной массив состоит из 30, то есть кратен 15, то нужно до $i+15 прописывать? И там будет до запись, 45 элементов, 60 эл. и т.д.

Comment: @dizznt кратно количеству элементов в строке. По-хорошему можно просто аналогичным способом разбить массивы на массивы по Х значений, а с ними уже работать.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял, попробую осуществить.